# Problema na execução do depurador Visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, debug

Estou com um problema no meu projeto, utilizo o ASP.NET MVC 5 e de um tempo para cá eu recebo essa mensagem sempre que executo meu projeto, o problema não é o visual studio instalado na maquina([como nessa solução](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/53705/error-the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed-run-s.html)) pois meus colegas de trabalho tem o mesmo problema quando utilizam na maquina deles.

Eu consigo rodar meu aplicativo tranquilo, o problema é que se está aparecendo essa mensagem há algo de errado e eu ja fiz 300 milhões de pesquisas e não resolvo.

A mensagem é:

> O depurador não foi instalado corretamento. Não é possível depurar o
>   tipo de código solicitado. Execute o programa de instalação para
>   reparar o depurador.

Eu tenho **certeza** de que não é o meu visual studio e sim o projeto. Alguém ja passou por algo parecido? Está dificil encontrar uma solução, segue o print do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: esse erro é quando vc tenta rodar testes automatizados? Pode ser o webdriver que não está instalado...

Comment: Não, esse erro ocorre quando eu vou executar a aplicação web

Comment: Instalei o SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2017 e estou com o mesmo problema. Parece que tem um número considerável de gente com este problema. Veja esta [questão no Fórum do SQL Server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ea1aadfd-7ae9-48aa-be01-d5bf518800b9/error-in-visual-studio-2017-integration-services-project-unable-to-start-debugging-the-debugger-is?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Neste mesmo forum no post acima, postei uma solução que rosolveu o meu caso (procura na página por gwarah). Espero que ajude no teu caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema se resolveu ao mudar a porta do projeto de `http://localhost:54345/` para alguma outra aleatória, exemplo `http://localhost:54348/`.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Limpe as pastas: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VS7Debug

2 - Fazer um recover do Visual Studio

OBS.: Isso pode ser causado por DLL's corrompidas. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yash/2007/09/20/debugger-not-working/

Answer (score 0):

Segundo [este artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb483187.aspx) da microsoft, vc deve seguir o seguinte passo:

> Se várias versões do Visual Studio tiverem sido instaladas e
>   desinstaladas no computador, a depuração do WF3 poderá falhar com uma
>   das duas possibilidades a seguir: Os pontos de interrupção não foram
>   atingidos. A seguinte mensagem é exibida: Não é possível iniciar a
>   depuração no servidor web. O depurador não está instalado
>   corretamente. Não é possível depurar o tipo de código solicitado.
>   Execute a instalação para instalar ou reparar o depurador. Se qualquer
>   um desses cenários ocorrer durante a depuração de fluxos de trabalho
>   do .NET Framework 3.0 ou 3.5, execute um reparo da instalação do
>   Visual Studio.

Comment: Eu disse que o problema é no **projeto** e não no Visual Studio, ja tentei esse processo :/

Comment: Então, mas a questão é que todos os lugares levam a mostrar que é problema do visual studio. Por exemplo, você afirmou que não é, mas como não comprovou, eu tentei seguir a linha de que poderia ser este problema. Qual VS você usa? já tentou outra versão? o erro persistiu? tente atualizar seu .net framework...